# Which design pattern to do this?

Tags: design-patterns, workflow

I've got a process something like a workflow, assume it like this:

1. Prepare
2. Eat

   - Take your stuff to bin
   - Clean up the table

Now what I want to do is even the user cancels the "Eat" event I want them to "Clean up the table" same goes for "Prepare" and "Take your stuff to bin" stages.

Currently in my implementation I had to do several checks and sometimes I end up like calling "Clean up table" twice, and some other branching issues when I add couple of more steps.

Is there any well defined design pattern to deal with this kind of flows? (*AFAIR there was one I just can't recall the name of it.*)

Comment: just slap the kids around......kidding!! :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is solved with the [State pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternState.aspx).  If you test drive the logic it'll go smoothly.

Comment: This was the one I was thinking of. Quite flexible for a workflow. Cheers.

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like [Template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Or you can do this via composition and [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

If you start to have complicated logic, then [State pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) could be better.

Answer (score 3):

If you're working in C++: [Resource Acquisition is Initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

This problem generally hasn't been solved well in languages without some sort of deterministic finalisation (C#, Java etc.)

Answer (score 3):

State Pattern my firend is what will make this work at end.

Answer (score 2):

In C#/.NET, we have the [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) pattern. I'm sure you could implement something similar in another language, whether or not it has a garbage collector (though the implementation would differ slightly).

Regarding the workflow aspect of this, I would just follow the design pattern of web services in WCF (i.e. `Begin` and `Cancel` methods). If you don't consider it overkill for your circumstances, the [Windows Workflow Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328.aspx) may be the best way to go.

Comment: actually IDisposable is not a bad idea, currently I kept a copy of the object even after the final step but I might refactor it.